# Yii2: Controller action parameters with a dash?

Tags: php, yii, controller, yii2, action

If I have a URL like `https://example.com/controller/action?customer-id=7414` how do I get `customer-id` in my action parameters? Since a dash is not allowed in variables names I cannot do the following!

```php
public function actionContact($customer-id) {   //syntax error! :)
    // ...
}
```

Documentation is usually excellent but on this exact point it's just silent. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `yii\web\Controller` calls action it only binds parameters which names match exactly. Dash cannot be used in variable name in PHP so there is no way it will ever match like that.

If you really want to have param in URL as `customer-id=XXX` then easiest thing you can do, is skip param in action method definition and get it during action itself:

```php
public function actionContact() {
    $customerId = $this->request->get('customer-id');
    // or
    $customerId = \Yii::$app->request->get('customer-id');

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That'll work - it won't throw an exception if the parameter is not provided though like it otherwise would. But will have to do that myself I guess...